# Launch an editor from within Racket

Tags: terminal, racket

I'm writing a Racket program that runs in the terminal. And I'd like to be able to launch a light editor (vi, pico etc.) from inside it, to edit some text, and then, when closed, return it to the program.

I know it's possible to do something like this in shell-script. Is it possible in Racket? If so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use the [`system`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/subprocess.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fsystem..rkt%29._system%29%29) function and its variants like `system*`.

Example:

```
#lang racket

(define file (make-temporary-file))

;; run the editor you want here and pass it the file name
(system* (find-executable-path "vim") (path->string file))

;; do whatever processing you want to do on the file here
(file->string file)
```

This creates a temporary file, lets vim edit it, and then reads the file back.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative would be using the text% class for the editing and then write the result to a file in the usual I/O-way. I supervised a intro course project that used that method last year, and it worked out well for them.

https://docs.racket-lang.org/gui/text_.html